# Python guilds.join trouble with Discord OAuth2

Tags: python-3.x, flask, oauth-2.0, flask-login

I'm learning Flask and Discord OAuth2, and I want to learn how to use guilds.join to join a guild. Can someone point me in the right direction, because I have been looking and I couldn't figure it out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I just used [Flask-Discord](https://github.com/thec0sm0s/Flask-Discord) and it made things so much easier. If you are looking to do Python and Discord OAuth2, Flask-Discord is the way to go!